# Is it possible to create two servers from one script in NodeJs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is it possible to create normal webserver for pages and websocket service from one nodejs script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, and in fact this is what pretty much almost happens. A single TCP listener handles both HTTP requests as well as web socket requests, which start as an HTTP request but then change protocols to a raw TCP web socket. All the examples on [socket.io](http://socket.io/) illustrate this.

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(app)
  , fs = require('fs')

app.listen(80);

function handler (req, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html',
  function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading index.html');
    }

    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });
}

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```